# how can i return updated variable value from vue cli method

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I written code to increment and decrements the value using vue cli methods but the methods not returning anything. But the default values are printing on the html how can I get methods value also.

```
----------
//html
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="counter">
                <center>Adults</center>
                <div class="row"> 
                  <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="fas fa-minus" v-on:click="adec"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <center>{{adult}}</center>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <span class="fas fa-plus"  v-on:click="ainc"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
----------
vue.js code 

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      adult:1,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    ainc(){
     this.adult++;
    },
    adec(){
     this.adult--;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear that you want here. As written, `adult` should be rendered in the DOM with the current value as you increment and decrement it. What else do you want?

Comment: But Bert actually the value is not increment or decrements the increment and decrements methods not working

Comment: It should. Here is your code working (with bootstrap/font-awesome removed). https://codesandbox.io/s/5vjq882n3k

Comment: Dear Bert now i got where i did the mistake actually instead of buttons i used font awesome icons for + and - with span tag so the v-on:click logic didn't executed thanks buddy due to your code i got thought to try once with buttons that's worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this helps, but let me know if it helps:

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button v-on:click="adec">minus</button> adult: {{adult}} | adec(): {{ainc()}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <button v-on:click="ainc">plus</button> adult: {{adult}} |  ainc(): {{adec()}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      adult: 1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ainc() {
      this.adult += 1;
      return this.adult;
    },
    adec() {
      this.adult -= 1;
      return this.adult;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```